# Is it possible to create an array of list in TCL?

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

I want to use an array of list in tcl. This is how i initialized it:

```
for {set i 0} {$i<5} {incr i} {
     set defer_req$i {}
}
```

Its working fine. But when i use these lists in procedure, it gives an error "can't read defer_req, no such variable". please help me out

Answer (score 4):

You have not created an array. You have created a set of variables with a common prefix of 'defer_req' and a numeric suffix. As given in the [variable syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M11) part of the Tcl manual, array addressing uses parentheses. So your assignment statement should be

```
set defer_req($i) {}
```

and in later code that uses this you might use something like:

```
puts $defer_req($memberName)
```

You don't have to use an array - you could leave your code as it stands, creating a set of similarly named variables. In that case to use the value you would need:

```
puts [set defer_req$memberName]
```

which first runs the set statement (the part within the braces) and expands $membername into a suffix creating the full variable name. Then the [set command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/set.htm) with only one argument returns the value of the named variable.

The naive version ($defer_req$memberName) would try to substitute in the value of a variable called defer_req and concatenate its value with that of a variable called memberName.

Answer (score 1):

```
 array set ar {}
 set ar(key) {}
 for {set i 0} {$i < 100} {incr i} {
   lappend ar(key) $i
 }
 puts $ar(key)
```